# Run prolog and look at the result in browser

Tags: prolog

I want to run a file prolog `test.pl` and look at the result in browser and I added three lines in file prolog. But it doesn't work. Can you guys tell me why?  all

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YLTT.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a `http_handler` to tell prolog which predicate it should run when it receives a request.

```
% tells prolog to call process_request
:- http_handler(root(.), process_request, []).

process_request(_Request) :-
    % your code here
    .
```

A simple "Hello World" example example can be found [here](http://www.swi-prolog.org/howto/http/HelloText.html); look [here](http://www.pathwayslms.com/swipltuts/html/index.html) for a more detailed tutorial.